# material-ui wrapping Tab component with Link

Tags: material-ui

I need to wrap the `Tab` components with a react-router `Link` compoenent. but considering the following code, when clicking on tabs yields no result. if it means the Tabs component must be direct parent of all Tab(s) component then how do I apply Link component?

```html
      <Tabs
        value={tab}
        onChange={(e, v) => setTab(v)} 
      >
        <Link to={`${props.match.url}`}>
          <Tab label="Content" />
        </Link>
        <Link to={`${props.match.url}/comment`}>
          <Tab label="Comment" /
        </Link>
        <Link to={`${props.match.url}/create`}>
          <Tab label="Create" />
        </Link>
      </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can provide Tab a *component* prop:

```
  <Tabs
    value={tab}
    onChange={(e, v) => setTab(v)} 
  >
      <Tab component={Link} to={`${props.match.url}`} label="Content" />
      <Tab component={Link} to={`${props.match.url}/comment`} label="Comment" />
      <Tab component={Link} to={`${props.match.url}/create`} label="Create" />
  </Tabs>
```